# Diagonal lines in polygon in ROS Stage

Tags: ros, simulation, stageros, stage, world

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone

My Stage just can't display the "block" section world file correctly in Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. All the object in Stage world are all has diagonal lines in polygon. The same world file is displaying correctly in Stage4 on Mac. Is anyone know what cause this problem? and how to fix it.

Thank you for the help.

This is my system: Max OSX 10.6.8 - VMware Fusion 5.0.2 , install Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, ROS-Fuerte .

```
 rosrun stage stage /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/share/stage/worlds/simple.world
```

Screen shot form my Stage4 simple.world on Ubuntu and Mac

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59767/diagonal-lines-in-polygon-in-ros-stage/) by [bombilee](https://answers.ros.org/users/4584/bombilee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After working on this problem for a while. Finally I can confirm this is graphic card driver related issue. If you have correct graphic driver with hardware GPU acceleration, the diagonal line will not show up. I still have problem with HD4000 driver on Ubuntu 12.04 or display in VMware.

---

Originally posted by [bombilee](https://answers.ros.org/users/4584/bombilee/) with karma: 86 on 2013-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0